# Why are subsequent Enterprises designated NCC?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I seem to recall that in TOS the 'NCC' designation referred to "***Constitution Class***" yet all Federation starships seem to have that designation, regardless.

Shouldn't the Enterprise-D be *N**G**C-1701*, for example?

Comment: Welcome Woody. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when. You've a couple of questions here, ideally they should be posted in their own threads.

Comment: _"I seem to recall that in TOS the "NCC" designation referred to "Constitution Class.""_ You probably should've done some checking to confirm that before posting this question, as that recollection is almost certainly inaccurate, meaning that this question is based on a false premise.

Comment: "NCC" stood for "Naval Construction Contract", and I believe that the "NX" designations were said to stand for "Naval Experimental".

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/NCC#Background_information

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "'NCC' stood for 'Naval Construction Contract'" is aprocryphal/not canon, [originating in Franz Joseph's 1975 *Star Trek Blueprints*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/NCC#Background_information).

Answer (score 3):

'NCC' is a registry prefix not an abbreviation.

> A second letter indicating the aircraft's airworthiness category
> followed the N and preceded the identification numbers. These
> airworthiness indicators were; "C" for standard, "R" for restricted,
> "X" for experimental, and later an "L" for limited, (for example,
> NC1234).[See FAA guide](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/aircraft_nnumber_history)

Jeffries (the creator) was mistaken about the letter "C" being for "commercial" planes.

The last "C" seems to have been added by Jeffries for mostly aesthetic reasons. [MA Wiki](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/NCC#Background_information)